# How to prove $0\le \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i+\frac{1}{i}}-\ln{\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

> Let $$x_{n}=\dfrac{1}{1+1}+\dfrac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n+\frac{1}{n}}
> -\ln{\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{2}}},n=1,2,\cdots$$
>   Show that
>   $a=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$ exist and $0\le a\le\dfrac{1}{2}$

I know
since
$$\dfrac{1}{i+\dfrac{1}{i}}<\dfrac{1}{i}$$
so
$$x_{n}<1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}-\ln{n}+\dfrac{1}{2}$$
and use Euler identity
$$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}-\ln{n}=C,n\to\infty$$
and
$$x_{n}>\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\ln{n}+\dfrac{1}{2}$$
and then I can't

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
for $x\geq 1$. It is easy to cheack that it is decreasing. Note also that a primitive of $f$ is 
$$F(x)=\frac12\log(1+x^2)$$

Define also, for $n\geq 1$,
$$a_n=\int_n^{n+1} [f(x)-f(n+1)]dx$$

Now,
$$\begin{align}
0&\leq a_n=F(n+1)-F(n)-f(n+1)\\
&\leq f(n)-f(n+1)
\end{align}$$

Now it is clear that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, and its sum is bounded by
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty[f(n)-f(n+1)]=f(1)=\frac12$$
but
$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k=F(n+1)-F(1)-\sum_{k=1}^nf(k+1)$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[F(n)-\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\log\sqrt{1+n^2}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac1k}\right]=F(1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}x_n&=\frac{1}{1+1/1}+\frac{1}{2+1/2}+...+\frac{1}{n+1/n}-\ln(\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}})\\&=\frac{1}{1^2+1}+\frac{2}{2^2+1}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+1}-\ln(n)+\frac{\ln2}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1}(1-\frac{1}{1^2+1})+\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2^2+1})+...+\frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n^2+1})-\ln(n)+\frac{\ln2}{2}\\
&=(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n))-(\frac{1}{1(1^2+1)}+\frac{1}{2(2^2+1)}+...+\frac{1}{n(n^2+1)})+\frac{\ln2}{2}\\&
\leq (1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n))-(\frac{1}{1(1^2+1^2)}+\frac{1}{2(2^2+2^2)}+...+\frac{1}{n(n^2+n^2)})+\frac{\ln2}{2}\\&
=(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n))-\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{n^3})+\frac{\ln2}{2}=y_n
\end{align}
So we have $x_n\leq y_n$ for all $n$. On the other hand we have 
\begin{align}
x_n&=(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n))-(\frac{1}{1(1^2+1)}+\frac{1}{2(2^2+1)}+...+\frac{1}{n(n^2+1)})+\frac{\ln2}{2}\\
&\geq(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n))-(1+\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{n^3})+\frac{\ln2}{2}=z_n
\end{align}
Hence $z_n\leq x_n\leq y_n$ for all $n$.
Now $$\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$$
But $$\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\gamma-\zeta(3)+\frac{\ln2}{2}>-0.28$$
and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=\gamma-\frac{\zeta(3)}{2}+\frac{\ln2}{2}<0.33<\frac{1}{2}$$
So 
$$-0.28<\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n<\frac{1}{2}$$